# .NET WPF Window FadeIn and FadeOut Animation

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, window

Below is code snippets of a window FadeIn and FadeOut animation:

```
// Create the fade in storyboard
fadeInStoryboard = new Storyboard();
fadeInStoryboard.Completed += new EventHandler(fadeInStoryboard_Completed);
DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.30)));
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, this);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
fadeInStoryboard.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);

// Create the fade out storyboard
fadeOutStoryboard = new Storyboard();
fadeOutStoryboard.Completed += new EventHandler(fadeOutStoryboard_Completed);
DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.30)));
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeOutAnimation, this);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOutAnimation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));
fadeOutStoryboard.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation);
```

Below are the helper methods which trigger the animation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fades the window in.
/// </summary>
public void FadeIn()
{
   // Begin fade in animation
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(fadeInStoryboard.Begin), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
}

/// <summary>
/// Fades the window out.
/// </summary>
public void FadeOut()
{
   // Begin fade out animation
   this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(fadeOutStoryboard.Begin), DispatcherPriority.Render, null);
}
```

The code works great except for two problems:

1. On FadeIn() the window starts off with an ugly black background then animates correctly.
2. On FadeOut() animates correctly then the window ends off with an ugly black background.

Why is this happening? How do i make this animation run smoothly without the black background hitch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to set `AllowsTransparency` to `true` on the `Window` for it to come up from fully transparent.

Unfortunately this is only possible with `WindowStyle=None`, so you would have to implement your own title bar.

This brings forth some nasty performance issues, since the window cannot be hardware rendered anymore. If you go this way I strongly suggest setting `RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode` to `RenderMode.SoftwareOnly` (.NET 4.0 or higher) on the UI thread to get acceptable performance in simple compositions.

Comment: Hi MrDosu. Thanks for the answer. I use customised WPF windows, as such such the WindowStyle=None proeprty is already set. Will set RenderOptions.SoftwareOnly for performance gains. I am on VS 2010 .NET 4.0 :)

Comment: Layered Windows (WindowStyle=None, AllowsTransparency=True, Background=Transparent) can be hardware rendered on Windows Vista or later.