# Window transition in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, animation

I am trying to perform fade in transition on a Window. I am able to do the transition but only to the contents of the window. I mean the frame of the window and title bar are not transforming like the content in it. Please check the XAML code below and see what has to be done for the whole window to fade in.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.newwindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="newwindow" Height="295" Width="371" PreviewStylusInRange="Window_PreviewStylusInRange">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>


<Grid Height="257" Width="349">
    <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,0,0,112" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="127" Background="#FFDB1F1F" />


    </Grid>
```

I am using VS 2010 with .NET 3.5.

Thank you.

Comment: See (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3767188/773118) for some pointers.

Comment: Please don't edit your question if you have nothing meaningful to add to it.

Comment: I am sorry but my question got older so thought editing it would maybe make it seen by all.